# MarkMagic formats to generate Start Code B and <FNC1>?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I've hit a problem using MarkMagic (JMagic 8.1) to generate labels. We're required to generate a barcode for a Canadian zipcode (alphanumeric, six chars) with start code B, henceforth `<B>`, followed by `<FNC1>`, then the zip code. MarkMagic will only generate `<FNC1>` if I use format **UCC 128**, but this fails to encode the alphanumerics. **Code 128 Subset B** generates `<B>`, but I've found no way to get it to generate `<FNC1>`.

The zebra code is another story. I figured out that the ZPL code for `<B>` + `<FNC1>` is `>:>8`. This works perfectly! But I've not been able to get MarkMagic to generate that code. I can only get it by editing the spool file (ZPL code) manually.

Before you ask -- I tried adding a data field with `>:>8` prior to the zip code field, in an attempt at ZPL code injection. I've successfully used this method to add UTF-8 special chars, including `^FH^FD`. Unfortunately MarkMagic stripped the `>:>8` characters

Any suggestions on settings in MarkMagic that I might have missed, a way to prevent MarkMagic from stripping my ZPL code, or other workaround ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the approach that worked was what I tried:

> Adding a data field with >:>8 prior to the zip code field, in an attempt at ZPL code injection.

It didn't work before because of a bug in the export system for MarkMagic. The label file didn't get updated with the fix at all.